# How to merge intelligently GPS sensors?

Tags: gps

I'm working on an application with a lot of GPS sensors, for each vehicle and person in a scene.

I want to show a vehicle and his occupants in the same marker. But I can't get the vehicle occupants list from the system, I only have GPS positions and object type (firetruck, policeman, car driver, etc…).

I'm looking for an existing model or library doing this kind of merge.

The simple approach can be to merge closest sensors from a vehicle into it, but sometimes you have a lot of people outside of a vehicle.

I can use the historical data, if some sensors are moving at the same speed and are near since a long time, I can consider that they are in the same vehicle. But it's a homemade system and it's maybe not very good.

Is there a good way?

Answer (score 1):

My personal point of view, why not create a geospatial buffer (e.g. a circle or rectangle) around each incoming coordinate from moving vehicles? If any people or occupants locate in the defined buffer, then you could consider they are quite close to the vehicle, and then you can snap these occupants to the marker. You can define the size of the buffer to filter the occupants. This is feasible with some easy point-in-polygon check in GIS.

Comment: It's a good start and I think that I will start to do it.

But a problem is for example when a vehicle is travelling at 100km/h next to a man standing on the side of the road. It doesn't make sense to include it in the vehicle.

Comment: In addition to the output of location, I think GPS can also provide parameters like velocity (i.e. speed) as well. I guess you could obtain speeds from GPRMC or transform it from GPGGA, coupled with location to determine the relationships between vehicle and occupants/nearby man. Why not set two variables to determine this relationship? For example, the occupants should be people coincided with location proximity and close-to speed with vehicle.